# Pandas json_normalize Not Working With Large JSON File In Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to normalize a large (about 900 MB) json file into a pandas DataFrame using the json_normalize() function. This works for all the other files I am processing (which range from  about 150-500 MB in size), although they each take a few minutes to finish. However with this file it seems to just run forever and never finishes. I have tried reading the json file directly into a DataFrame using read_json() before normalizing as well as simply loading the json from the file with json.loads(). Both methods have the same result. The code I am using is:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

path = mf.getPath('dataFile.json')
testTrials = json.loads(open(path)) #testTrials = pd.read_json(path)
testTrials = json_normalize(testTrials['rows'])
```

Comment: How much RAM does your system have? How nested is your data structure? Do you need all the data loaded into the frame? Given `nested_to_record` (used by `json_normalize`) does a deep copy for each dict, you will need a lot of memory, I think more than 3-4Gb. See how much RAM uses the 500MB file for an estimate.

Comment: @Rho it caps out the available 8 GB of ram. I used a new method that uses ijson to read line by line, this allows the process to finish but it takes 30 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the big JSON file into serveral chunks and process one chunk a time. Code like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

dfs = []
chunk_size = 1000
for json in grouper(jsons,chunk_size):
    df = json_normalize(json)
    dfs.append(df)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: One potential issue here is if the json objects do not all contain the same schema. That happens to be my case, so I need to use json_normalize on the entire dataset "at once" for it to infer the correct schema.